# Strict standards: Non-static method MenuHelper::getArticleByID() should not be called statically in

Tags: php, joomla

Just started to learn joomla and in kinda bad at php i don't know how i can make Non-static calling.
Getting this error : Strict standards: Non-static method MenuHelper::getArticleByID() should not be called statically in

```
<?php 

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$base = JURI::base(true);
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
$item = $menu->getMenu();

include __DIR__ . '/helper.php';

?>
<div class="container">
<div class="item support">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">
            <span class="name"><a href="<?php echo $item[106]->flink; ?>" class="rumble"><?php echo $item[106]->title; ?></a></span>
            <span class="icon"><img src="<?php echo $base; ?>/templates/tehnos/images/man.png" alt="" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h3><?php echo MenuHelper::getArticleByID(2)->title; ?></h3>
            <?php echo MenuHelper::getArticleByID(2)->introtext; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item center">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">+
            <span class="name"><a href="<?php echo $item[107]->flink; ?>" class="rumble"><?php echo $item[107]->title; ?></a></span>
            <span class="icon"><img src="<?php echo $base; ?>/templates/tehnos/images/man.png" alt="" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h3><?php echo MenuHelper::getArticleByID(3)->title; ?></h3>
            <?php echo MenuHelper::getArticleByID(3)->introtext; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item service">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">
            <span class="name"><a href="<?php echo $item[108]->flink; ?>" class="rumble"><?php echo $item[108]->title; ?></a></span>
            <span class="icon"><img src="<?php echo $base; ?>/templates/tehnos/images/man.png" alt="" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h3><?php echo MenuHelper::getArticleByID(4)->title; ?></h3>
            <?php echo MenuHelper::getArticleByID(4)->introtext; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item events">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">
            <span class="name"><a href="<?php echo $item[109]->flink; ?>" class="rumble"><?php echo $item[109]->title; ?></a></span>
            <span class="icon"><img src="<?php echo $base; ?>/templates/tehnos/images/man.png" alt="" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <?php echo MenuHelper::getArticleByID(5)->introtext; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item standards">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">
            <span class="name"><a href="<?php echo $item[110]->flink; ?>" class="rumble"><?php echo $item[110]->title; ?></a></span>
            <span class="icon"><img src="<?php echo $base; ?>/templates/tehnos/images/man.png" alt="" /></span>
        </div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="text">
            <?php echo MenuHelper::getArticleByID(6)->introtext; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error message tells you already, that the method in MenuHelper doesn't seemed to be defined as a

```
public static function getArticleByID (...)
```

So what you can do is to fetch one instance of the MenuHelper after the include.

```
$menuHelper = new MenuHelper();
```

And then replace

```
MenuHelper::getArticleByID()
```

with

```
$menuHelper->getArticleByID()
```

in your code. Now you should get rid of the error message.

Comment: **Thank you wery much @TheColaKid**